# Name attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

You can get html elements like so

```
document.forms[0].elementName
```

However what if more than one element is sharing that name, doesn't that create a conflict in javascript? Or should i just use ids instead. Thank you.

Radio Buttons require same name

Comment: It will return an array of elements if there are more than one.

Comment: Unless the name is part of an array (`name="foo[]"`), it's going to cause a problem with your HTML, too.  Can you post some additional code so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: Diodeus would I be required to use elements[] collection ? or elementName will return the array ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no conflict since it's perfectly fine having multiple elements with the same name (e.g. think a group of radiobox, sharing the same name) and in that case the reference is not a single node but a node collection

Anyway if you access elements by `id` you can avoid any possible problems (since they must be unique in page)

Comment: I had to select one answer, however wanted to mention that Diodeus gave me the answer as a comment. The missing link was that it returns a "collection" if more than one element has that name.

Comment: @Marin Note that you can upvote other answers that helped you as well even though you can accept only one `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's no conflict, but you should use unique names for different inputs or groups (and yes, Diodeus I'm referring to radio buttons) inside the same form.

You could have to elements with the same name in the same form and your expression's result would be an array of elements that have the same name, but as you stated, that brings confusion.

Take a look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/J6yJr/ (look at the console);

You should use whatever you are more comfortable with; you can use names, ids or any other selectors as long as they work and they make sense. It really depends on the html markup structure and your coding style.

Ex: which of the following would you use?

```
document.getElementById('e-mail');
document.getQuerySelectorAll('#e-mail[type=email]');
document.forms[0]['e-mail'][n];
```

Comment: What about radio buttons? They will not work if each has an unique name.

Answer (score 0):

the following will give you sort of an array (a nodeList) of those elements:

```
    document.getElementsByName("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't even apply with your code, which returns the element name for the DOM element it is called on. There can't possibly be a "conflict" there—its name is its name.

If you do `documentgetElementsByName("myname");`, I defer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName):

> Returns a list of elements with a given name in the HTML document.

The key being "list"; if there is more than one matching, it will return a list of all those that match.